# Prove that $S$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $g_1g_2 \in S$ for all $g_1,g_1 \in S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is the second part to a previous question I had. 
The first part can be found here.

[Show that there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $g^k=1_G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733217/show-that-there-exists-a-positive-integer-k-such-that-gk-1g)

Here's the second:

Let $G$ be a group and let $S$ be a (non-empty) finite subset of $G$.

Prove that $S$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $g_1g_2 \in S$ for all $g_1,g_1 \in S$

This question almost seems trivially intuitive to me since if $S$ is a subgroup of $G$ then of course $g_1g_2 \in S$ for all $g_1,g_2 \in S$, since a subgroup is closed under operation.

For the other direction since $G$ has inverse, if $g_1g_2 \in S$ for all $g_1,g_2 \in S$, then $g_1^{-1} g_2 = g_1'g_2 \in S \subseteq G $ (where $g_1'=g_1^{-1}$). So the subgroup test has been satisfied.

Comment: -1 Surely you can do it after being given the first part? What do you have to prove to show that $S$ is a group?

Comment: You should ask yourself "so which part of the definition of being a subgroup seems to be missing here?"

Comment: Hint. The previous question says you have the identity, and inverses. Since it's a subset of a group you have associativity. What group property is missing?

Comment: Thanks for your responses everyone!

So that the product of two elements is itself in the group?
But that's almost trivial then? Is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is a subgroup of $G$ then clearly $S$ is closed under multiplication, namely $g_1g_2\in S$ for every $g_1,g_2\in S$.

On the other hand, let $g\in S$. I want to show that $1\in S$ and $g^{-1}\in S$. Say $H$ is the set $\{g, g^2, g^3,...\}$. For hypothesis, $H\subseteq S$ and so $H$ is finite, hence there are $l,n$ with $l>n$, such that $g^l=g^n$, namely $1=g^{l-n}\in H\subseteq S$. At the same time you can deduce that $1=gg^{l-n-1}$ to obtain that $g^{-1}=g^{l-n-1}\in H\subseteq S$. Associativity follows because every element in $S$ is an element of a group. So for every $g_1,g_2,g_3\in S\subseteq G$ you have $(g_1g_2)g_3=g_1(g_2g_3).$

Answer (score 1):

The claim as it is written is false, as $\;\Bbb N\subset\Bbb Z\;$ proves. If $\;S\;$ is *finite*  and non-empty then the claim is true.